# Hidden Field Value Not Getting Filled JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML table append using jQuery as follows which fires on a button click

```
$("#listadd").click(function() {


    if (validateListAdd()) {

        var mcode = $("#mcodehidden").val();

        if(checkItemDuplicates(mcode)) {
            var mname = $("#mnamehidden").val();
            var sellprice = $("#sellprice").val();
            var cost = $("#cost").val();
            var qty = $("#qty").val();
            var remark = $("#remark").val();
            var subtotal = sellprice * qty;
            alert(qty);

            $("#productlist tbody").append('<tr  class="sumrow"><td><input id="hdqty" type="hidden" name="tblqty[]" value="' + qty + '"><input id="hdsubtotal" type="hidden" name="tblsubtotal[]" value="' + subtotal + '"><input type="hidden" name="tblmcode[]" value="' + mcode + '">' + mcode + '<input type="hidden" name="tblcost[]" value=' + cost + ' ></td><td><input type="hidden" name="tblmname[]" value="' + mname + '">' + mname  + '</td><td id="tdprice"><input type="hidden" name="tblsellprice[]" value=' + sellprice + '>' + sellprice + '</td><td id="tdqty">' + qty + '</td><td  class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td><td><input type="hidden" name="tblremark[]" value=' + remark + '>' + remark + '</td><td><center><button type="button" class="edit" title="Edit this row"></center></td><td><center><button type="button" class="delete" title="Remove this row"></center></td></tr>');

            $('[id$=mcode]').val("");
            $('[id$=mname]').val("");
            $('[id$=sellprice]').val("");
            $('[id$=qty]').val("");
            $('[id$=mcodehidden]').val("");
            $('[id$=mnamehidden]').val("");

            calculateTotal();
        }else{

            alert("Sorry, You have already added this item");

        }

    } else {

        alert("You have entered invalid data, Please check again");

    }

});
```

The problem is the value of the hidden field #hdqty is not getting filled by the var "qty" but which shows up the value correctly in the alert that I have used in here. When I inspected the element(table row) in the browser, it shows the hidden field as

```
<input id="hdqty" type="hidden" name="tblqty[]" value>
```

Can anyone point me out the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the value of the `#hdqty` field in the string you build, however the below line removes the value almost immediately:

```
$('[id$=qty]').val("");
```

The selector above matches any element that has an `id` attribute that *ends with* `qty`.

Remove that line, or change the selector to better fit your requirements, and your code will work.

Comment: But it is after appending the line to the table right?

Comment: That's right. You append the `#hdqty` field with a value, then the selector above removes the value.

Comment: Yes you are correct, but after adding it to the table i need to set the value again to blank so I can add the next row, how can I do that?

Comment: Yes it works by removing that line, but the problem is I need to empty the #qty text field after appending the line, what should I do for that?

Answer (score 1):

Paste this

```
$("#productlist tbody").append('<tr  class="sumrow"><td><input id="hdqty" type="hidden" name="tblqty[]" value="' + qty + '"/><input id="hdsubtotal" type="hidden" name="tblsubtotal[]" value="' + subtotal + '"/><input type="hidden" name="tblmcode[]" value="' + mcode + '"/>' + mcode + '<input type="hidden" name="tblcost[]" value=' + cost + ' /></td><td><input type="hidden" name="tblmname[]" value="' + mname + '">' + mname  + '</td><td id="tdprice"><input type="hidden" name="tblsellprice[]" value=' + sellprice + '>' + sellprice + '</td><td id="tdqty">' + qty + '</td><td  class="subtotal">' + subtotal + '</td><td><input type="hidden" name="tblremark[]" value=' + remark + '>' + remark + '</td><td><center><button type="button" class="edit" title="Edit this row"></center></td><td><center><button type="button" class="delete" title="Remove this row"></center></td></tr>');
```

also paste this line before the above code

```
$('[id$=qty]').val("");
```